# Overloading SpringBoot @PostMapping controller method not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have faced some challenge and to describe shortly I created test application. Code you can see and error you can see below.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/test",params = { "a", "b" })
    public String test(@RequestPart MultipartFile a, @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile b) {
        return "test1";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/test", params = { "b" })
    public String test(@RequestPart MultipartFile b) {
        return "test2";
    }
}
```

I`m trying to execute this request from postman:

[image: Postman Request]

And I`m getting such error in logs:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException:
Parameter conditions "a, b" OR "b" not met for actual request parameters: ]
```

The thing is, if I will put parameters also in postman (not in body, in request url: `localhost:8080/test?b=anything`) it will work fine, but I don`t need request params in url.

Is there some possible way to make it work?

Comment: You should change `@RequestPart MultipartFile a` to `@RequestParam(value = "a") MultipartFile a`. Also ensure that `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` is sent as request header.

Comment: You don't need `params`, just change `@RequestPart` to `@RequestParam`.

Comment: I try with @RequestParam(value = "a"). result - Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "a, b" OR "b" not met for actual request parameters: ]

Comment: One solution would be using Headers to do the overload as well, because only with different body parts, you cannot register a different method to same url. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers

Answer (score 1):

I am able to override @PostMapping. But the type of the parameter should be different.

```
  @PostMapping(value="/test" )
    public String testApi(@ModelAttribute MultipartDTO multipartDTO) {
        return "test1";
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/test" ,params = { "b" })
    public String test(@RequestParam String b) {
        return "test2";
    }
```

/** DTO **/

```
@Data
public class MultipartDTO{
private MultipartFile a;
private MultipartFile b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not map the same signature twice which contains the same Http methods then below error will occur.

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods
> ```

try this one

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String test(@RequestParam MultipartFile a, @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile b) {
        return "test1";
    }

    @PostMapping("/test2")
    public String test(@RequestParam MultipartFile b) {
        return "test2";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is key thing :) I need to overload method. And with GetMappings it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You should try something like below.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public String test(@RequestParam MultipartFile a, @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile b) {
        return "test1";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public String test(@RequestParam MultipartFile b) {
        return "test2";
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'testController' method. It doest`n works without params.

Comment: There cannot be 2 `@PostMapping`s with the same "value". They should show some difference in terms of "accepts", "consumes", etc.